# Extract all the following rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

`df`

```
A B
1 b0
2 a0
3 c0
5 c1
6 a1
7 b1
8 b2
```

The first row which starts with `a` is

`df[df.B.str.startswith("a")]`

```
A B
2 a0
```

I would like to extract the first row in column B that starts with a and every row after. My desired result is below

```
A B
2 a0
3 c0
5 c1
6 a1
7 b1
8 b2
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to select all rows following any "a" row, or just the one that immediately follows it? (Your example is unfortunately hard to interpret. Perhaps you need to change it to clarify.)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I edited my example and question. I would like to extract all the following rows.)

Comment: But your example shows all following rows _and_ the "a" row, too. So, which one do you want? Also, does an "a" row always exist?

Comment: I would like to extract "a" rows and all the following rows. therefore "a" rows always exist ! thank you for cooperation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a mask and use it for selection:

```
mask = df.B.str.startswith("a")
mask[~mask] = np.nan
df[mask.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0).astype(int) == 1]
```

Another option is to build an index range:

```
first = df[df.B.str.startswith("a")].index[0]
df.ix[first:]
```

The latter approach assumes that an "a" is always present.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, here is how you do it :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,2,3,5,6,7,8],
      'B' : ['b0','a0','c0','c1','a1','b1','b2']})
# index of the item beginning with a
index = df[df.B.str.startswith("a")].values.tolist()[0][0] 
desired_df = pd.concat([df.A[index-1:],df.B[index-1:]], axis = 1)
print desired_df
```

and you get:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

using `idxmax` to find first `True`

```
df.loc[df.B.str[0].eq('a').idxmax():]

   A   B
1  2  a0
2  3  c0
3  5  c1
4  6  a1
5  7  b1
6  8  b2
```